# Community Beta Invitation List

Tags: discussion

Just an idea we were throwing around to distribute beta invitations to active web application users.

Format is as follows (Keep edits to the one answer listed below)

> #### Blubrry App
>
> service to keep track of your blueberries
>
> - scr.im/blahbla - from name of Web Apps user
> - pingu@example.com - from name of another Web Apps user
>
> #### Bananaramalamadingdongadong
>
> share and geolocate the best places to eat bananas
>
> - bana.nr/invites/crazyCODE - from name of Web Apps user

Most invitations require you to provide an email address. If you don't want to post your email publicly then use http://scr.im to hide your email address.

For example my email address is http://scr.im/bdgr

Comment: Looks like we no longer use this as a collection hat

Answer (score 6):

**If you use a link below please edit it out.**

#### [Schemer](http://www.schemer.com/)

A Google project: Schemer is based on a simple yet powerful concept: schemes. A scheme is any activity you’d like to do.

- [22e3aua2dk62i](http://schemer.com/invite/22e3aua2dk62i)
- [2roelufg8es56](http://schemer.com/invite/2roelufg8es56)
- [h4j3ug6k3vkgo](http://schemer.com/invite/h4j3ug6k3vkgo)

#### [Duolingo](http://duolingo.com/)

Aims to crowdsource text translation

#### [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/)

What are you working on? Dribbble is show and tell for designers.

#### [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/)

A virtual pinboard to organize and share the things you love.

- [invite link](http://pinterest.com/invited/?email=philippeharewood+webapps2@gmail.com&invite=5a3a1ad5&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pinterest.com)
- [invite link](http://pinterest.com/invited/?email=philippeharewood+webapps4@gmail.com&invite=d6bd4587)
- [invite link](http://pinterest.com/invited/?email=philippeharewood+webapps3@gmail.com&invite=35389c2d&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pinterest.com)

#### [Dropmark](http://dropmark.com/)

Drop files right from your computer or the web to create organized collections—bringing together information like never before.

#### [Letterboxd](http://letterboxd.com/)

social site for sharing opinions in films as well as a personal movie diary

- [88LD2TSL](http://letterboxd.com/register/88LD2TSL)
- [W7T4CW6Q](http://letterboxd.com/register/W7T4CW6Q)
- [2J7ZUMKB](http://letterboxd.com/register/2J7ZUMKB)
- [EYPJ5JSN](http://letterboxd.com/register/EYPJ5JSN)

#### [Clipboard](http://www.clipboard.com/)

share parts of the web in clipboard formats

- [invite link](http://www.clipboard.com/register?token=4a816784f44575da2e2d49db95ba07ef7b23c276131416838311)
- [invite link](http://www.clipboard.com/register?token=4a816784f44575da2e2d49db95ba07ef7b23c2761321416883687)
- [invite link](http://www.clipboard.com/register?token=4a816784f44575da2e2d49db95ba07ef7b23c2761321416929712)
- [invite link](http://www.clipboard.com/register?token=4a816784f44575da2e2d49db95ba07ef7b23c2761321416711325)
- [invite link](http://www.clipboard.com/register?token=38d961333781925e490d7cf29f41a37407262cca1324662570910)

#### [Geeklist](http://geekli.st/)

A place for geeks to share what they've done, who they did it with and connect with great companies.

- [invite link](http://geekli.st/iAmBibhas/invite/562689D00B)
- [invite link](http://geekli.st/chanchal1987/invite/6EB1800BC8)